# Can I make a property refernence to different getter in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, getter-setter

I want to override the getter of a property in a class in python:

```
class Block(object) :

    def name():
        doc = "The name property."
        def fget(self):
            return self._name
        def fset(self, value):
            self._name = value
        def fdel(self):
            del self._name
        return locals()
    name = property(**name())

    def toString(self):
        string = "{0} {1} \n".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.name)
        return string
```

---

```
class Machine(Block) :

    def host():
        doc = "The host property."
        def fget(self):
            return self._host

        def fset(self, value):
            self._host = value

        def fdel(self):
            del self._host

        return locals()

    host = property(**host())

    name = property(**host())
```

I want the extended name property to return the host getter in Machine, so when i call toString(), the name becomes the host.

Comment: This is not Java. Don't use `toString`, use `__str__`.

Comment: Thanks for that... Helps understand python a bit better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it the other way around:

```
name = property(**host())
host = property(**host())
```

or just:

```
host = property(**host())
name = host
```

The way you're doing it now, `name = property(**host())` is working on the **property** `host`, which has substituted the method by then.